# How can I upload a file and store a file table into DB?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, file-upload, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js and Codeigniter to handle a article post with file upload process:

1. There is a form to post an article
2. There is an dropzone allow user to upload a file

Before user submit the article, they can upload files. And here, I need a file table in database to store the article ID and file name.

**My question is**:
Only after I click the submit form button, the article is store into database and I will get the article ID after that. But once I drag a file into dropzone, the file is uploaded. So how can I store the "article_id - file_name" pair into database?

Here is my code to upload a file:

PHP to upload the file:

```
public function upload() {
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetPath = getcwd() . '/uploads/';
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $fileName ;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);

    // store table in db
    $this->load->database(); // load database
    $this->db->insert('file_table', array('id'=> '', 'article_id' => '', 'file_name' => $fileName, 'created_time'=> date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));
    }
}
```

PHP for the form and dropzone:

```
<form>
...            
<div id="dropzone" class="dropzone">
   <div class="dz-message">
       Drop files here or click to upload.<br />
       <span class="note">(You might select multiple files here.)</span>
   </div>
</div>
...
</form>
```

Comment: you can use session.When file is uploaded set the file id into session.And when you save the article get the file id from session and save it with article id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `insert_id()` to get last inserted ID.

Comment: Thanks so much MarlZ15199.I finally solve the problem by inserting article ID in file table = 0 first and then update the article ID after I post the article and get the new ID with insert_id().

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the id autoincrement ? If so you don't need to pass it, you can pass null or skip the field. You have the filename in the $fileName variable from what I can see above.

Comment: Hi Angel, thanks so much for your response. Yes it is auto increment. I store the article in a table, and the file_table is another one. But I won't get the latest article id until I submit the article form and the upload action is done before submitting the form.